# sqlalchemy - how to manage this scenario - cyclic dependency

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

I have a database package which contains some modules namely student_table and a db module,

in student_table I have definition it's definition like this

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, MetaData, String, Column, Integer
metadata = MetaData()

class User(object):
        def __init__(self, user_id, name):
                self.user_id = user_id
                self.name = name

user_table = Table('twitter_user', metadata,
        Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True), 
        Column('name', String(100))
)
```

and in db.py I have database create functions, which like this

```
def prepareDB():
    """
    sets global variables based to access database
    """
    read_settings()
    engine = create_engine('mysql://'+setting_data["database_username"]+':'+setting_data["database_password"]+'@'+setting_data["database_host"]+'/'+setting_data["database_name"]+'?charset=utf8')
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    global session
    session = Session()
    metadata.create_all(engine)
    mapper(database.User, database.user_table)
```

my problem is metadata is required by db module to create engine and also by student module for definition however I don't see a way of doing so without creating cyclic dependency.

what can I do rectify this situation.

Comment: I don't see a cycle here.    student_table does not appear to need to import db.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just moved constant to separate file , now everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have used something equivalent to this.

```
holder = [None]
def getmetadata():
  if holder[0] is None:
    holder[0] = sqlalchemy.MetaData()
  return holder[0]

user_tablef = lambda metadata: Table('twitter_user', metadata,
        Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True), 
        Column('name', String(100))
)

# ...

user_table = user_tablef(getmetadata())
```

But this is not the cleanest thing in the world, and it's one reason a lot of people use the declarative style.